# How to route non-local IPs through VPC connected via Site-to-Site VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

We've got the following scenario in AWS:
There is a (working) Site-to-Site VPN connection to a VPC with CIDR 172.30.0.0/16 in which an EC2 instance is running and managing another OpenVPN connection with CIDR 172.27.76.0/22.
The desired behaviour is for requests to be routed through the Site-to-Site VPN the the OpenVPN connection through the EC2 instance, i.e. requests to 172.27.76.0/22 entering the Site-to-Site VPN should be routed to the EC2 instance.

It seems that the requests to the OpenVPN, which should end up at the EC2 instance in the VPC, do not get past the virtual private gateway or are not routed.
We assume that the VPCs route tables do not take effect here, but the virtual private gateway (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html#gateway-route-tables).

Is there a way to get the routing working in this setup?

We found two workarounds, but would like to stick with the Site-to-Site VPN connection.

1. We added the 172.27.76.0/22 CIDR as a secondary CIDR to the VPC and attached an additional ENI to the EC2 instance with multiple IP address ranges from the 172.27.76.0/22 (OpenVPN) CIDR. The additional ENI is deactivated in the EC2 instances OS to prevent conflicts with the OpenVPN tunnel interface. Additionally, a route table is associated with the virtual private gateway containing a route for 172.27.76.0/22 CIDR to the EC2 instance. In this case the requests are routed correctly, but one ends up with several restrictions concerning the additional ENIs and this is overall quite hacky. Also, this setup does not work if the OpenVPN CIDR is not added to the VPC (which we would prefer) since the route table for the virtual private gateway only allows routes overlapping with the VPC's CIDRs.
2. Using a Transit Gateway for the VPN connection to the VPC, the requests are indeed forwarded. We guess that since the Transit Gateway has attachments directly to subnets, the route table associated with these subnets take effect and allow routing of the OpenVPN CIDR to the EC2 instance. While this is an "easy" solution, it does cost a lot more.